# Objective-C timer or method restarted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to programming and have started by building an app of a kayaker kayacking through a river. The app has two images, one on the left of the screen and one on the right, that detect a swipe up gesture which causes the kayaker to row up or down on each side. There are rocks, with a timer that keeps adding to the rock's "y" position every time the timer runs, to cause the illusion that they are kayaker is moving towards them, when they are really the ones moving down. The problem is this, everything works but when the gestures are activated for some reason the rocks reappear back on top and start moving down again. Can anybody explain to me why this happens and how to fix it? Thanks so much.

This is the code on the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WRViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
    //Image View for the game mode
    UIImageView *bg;
    UIImageView *player;
    UIImageView *rock1;
    UIImageView *rock2;
    UIImageView *rock3;

    UIImageView *con_left;
    UIImageView *con_right;

    NSInteger gameState;

    CGPoint rocksOnCurrent;
    CGPoint current;

    NSArray * lRowUpArray;
    NSArray * lRowDownArray;
    NSArray * rRowUpArray;
    NSArray * rRowDownArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *bg;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *player;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *rock1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *rock2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *rock3;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *con_left;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *con_right;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger gameState;

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint rocksOnCurrent;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint current;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *lRowUpArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *lRowDownArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *rRowUpArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *rRowDownArray;

-(void)gameStatePlayNormal;

-(void) swipe_leftUp;
-(void) swipe_leftDown;
-(void) swipe_rightUp;
-(void) swipe_rightDown;

@end
```

This is what's in the .m file:
    #import "WRViewController.h"

```
@interface WRViewController ()

@end

#define kStateRunning 1
#define kStateGameOver 2

#define kCurrent 0.0045

@implementation WRViewController
@synthesize bg, player, rock1, rock2, rock3;
@synthesize con_left, con_right;
@synthesize gameState;
@synthesize rocksOnCurrent, current;
@synthesize lRowUpArray, lRowDownArray, rRowUpArray, rRowDownArray;


//Gesture actions called by gesture recognizers upon activation
-(void) swipe_leftDown{// The array inside is not causing the restarting
    NSArray * lRowDownArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage         imageNamed:@"k_lf1.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf2.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf3.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf4.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf5.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf6.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf7.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf8.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf9.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf10.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf11.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf12.png"], nil];
    player.animationImages = lRowDownArray;
    [player setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    player.animationDuration = 1.1;
    player.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
    [self.view addSubview:player];
    [player startAnimating];
    rock1.center = CGPointMake(rock1.center.x, rock1.center.y + rocksOnCurrent.y);
    rocksOnCurrent.x -= 0.4;
    rocksOnCurrent.y += 0.4;
}
-(void) swipe_leftUp{
    NSArray * lRowUpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf12.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf11.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf10.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf9.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf8.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf7.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf6.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf5.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf4.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf3.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"k_lf1.png"], nil];
    player.animationImages = lRowUpArray;
    [player setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    player.animationDuration = 1.1;
    player.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
    //[self.view addSubview:player];
    [player startAnimating];
}
//Did the above to swipe_RightDown and swipe_RightUp. Didn't add here to save space.

-(NSString *)pathOfFile{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolder = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentFolder stringByAppendingFormat:@"saverFile.plist"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    gameState = kStateRunning;
    rocksOnCurrent = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
    current = CGPointMake (0, kCurrent);

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    /////Gesture code for the row controllers
    //Left Row Up
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *con_leftUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe_leftUp)];
    con_leftUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    con_leftUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.con_left addGestureRecognizer:con_leftUp];

    //Left Row Down
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *con_leftDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe_leftDown)];
    con_leftDown.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    con_leftDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.con_left addGestureRecognizer:con_leftDown];
    //Right Row Up
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *con_rightUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe_rightUp)];
    con_rightUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    con_rightUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.con_right addGestureRecognizer:con_rightUp];
    //Right Row Down
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *con_rightDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe_rightDown)];
    con_rightDown.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    con_rightDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.con_right addGestureRecognizer:con_rightDown];
}

-(void)gameLoop {
    if (gameState == kStateRunning){
        [self gameStatePlayNormal];
    } else if (gameState == kStateGameOver){

    }
}
//Extra functions, so that they are not all in the game loop
-(void)gameStatePlayNormal{
    rocksOnCurrent.y += current.y;

    rock1.center = CGPointMake(rock1.center.x, rock1.center.y + rocksOnCurrent.y);
    rock2.center = CGPointMake(rock2.center.x, rock2.center.y + rocksOnCurrent.y);
    rock3.center = CGPointMake(rock3.center.x, rock3.center.y + rocksOnCurrent.y);

}

-(void)viewDidUnload {
    self.bg = nil;
    self.player = nil;
    self.rock1 = nil;
    self.rock2 = nil;
    self.rock3 = nil;
}

//Apple does not requires this, it seems.
/*-(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [bg release];
    [rock1 release];
    [rock2 release];
    [rock3 release];
}*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Simply put, whenever I activate a gesture the rocks go back to where they were originally almost as if restarting. rocksOnCurrent.y remains the same because the speed of the rocks seem to move faster every time I swipe. Any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: it may not be the answer but i still cant see it being good for performance creating a array with images each time the player swipes..good luck and hope you find your true answer though

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know how to create the array and reuse it after being created.

Comment: some where like view did load method of your view controller class you are using here you could create the arrays just as you did in your code and then remove their code from being called again in the swipe methods and player.animationImages = lrowdownarray will still work. You can call them any where in your class besides the neater code the more important thing is your app will run faster because the array of images is created ONCE and the app doesnt have to burn up all that power recreating the array shifting images around every time a user swipes.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. While on the .xib file, on the top right corner where there are 5 little tabs, the little tab all the way to the left (one that looks like a page) is the File Inspector. I guess the "Use Autolayout" is automatically checked when you start a new app. This was causing the problem.